# .htaccess header file

Tags: web-server, .htaccess

I'm wanting to include a header file in my .htaccess file. I've got the following code:

```
HeaderName header.htm
```

But for every subdirectory I have to copy the header in, is there any way to have it point to the same file on the top directory?

Cheers! Pete

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use /header.htm

Answer (score 0):

Was being a fool, backslashing not forwardslashing...

All sorted!